# Check if file exists in UWP

Tags: file, async-await, uwp, directory

I know this might be a duplicate, but the other questions I've found about this topic don't describe my problem well enough.

```
public bool FileExists(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filename != null)
            {
                // folder where the file is
                StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

                // check if file exists
                if (folder.TryGetItemAsync(filename) != null)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

My problem is that this method always returns true. `TryGetItemAsync(string name)` should return null if the file is not found. Instead, it returns `System.__ComObject`, regardless of if my parameter name is an actual file or not.

I am have checked multiple times that the file does exist in my `folder`.

Can anyone explain the behavior that it always returns `System.__ComObject`?

**EDIT 1**:
Some more information:

In my `main` class, I'm testing it like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Existing file = " + fileUtils.FileExists("Testfile1.txt"));
Debug.WriteLine("Not-Existing file = " + fileUtils.FileExists("Testfile2.txt"));
```

As you can see, the file does exist in the folder (and the folder in my code has the right path which leads to this folder):
[image: folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

folder.TryGetItemAsync() returns TResult object which stores the OPERATION not the RESULT of operation

to get the result just use await

```
var result = await folder.TryGetItemsAsync(filename);
```

or

```
var tRes = folder.TryGetItemsAsync(filename);
var outputFile = tRes.GetResults();
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

TryGetItemAsync is an asynchronous method. 
You need to use the await keyword if you want to get the result of the operation instead of the operation itself.

Instead of :

```
if (folder.TryGetItemAsync(filename) != null)
```

You can use :

```
var myFile=await folder.TryGetItemAsync(filename)
if(myFile!=null)
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. But in my case the method `FileExists` needs to be a synchronous method. That's why I marked RTDev's answer as the accepted answer because he showed a way to remain it synchronous.

Answer (score -2):

File.Exists is just works in Windows IOT and Windows too.

```
File.Exists(Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,"Testfile1.txt");
```

Comment: it doesn't work, file exists or not, it just returns false on UWP app